# Previous University Refusing to Supply Basic Details Required for VISA Application for Another Job

Tags: job, administration

I am a recent PhD graduate from a (large) university in the UK. I have a job offer that I have already accepted that is based in another country. I require basic information from my university for a VISA application (things like confirmation that I have finished my PhD, proof of salary, confirmation of roles/responsibilities etc.

However, I have been trying to get these from my university for over a month and they are refusing to supply anything until March at the earliest due to coronavirus. Due to the delay from this that has already occurred I have missed the start date for my job, and if I cannot get this before March I will lose my job offer.

Is this legal? Is there any avenue I can go down to force them to supply this immediately?

Comment: If you want to understand the law related to that and if you could force them, then perhaps that you need to talk with a lawyer.

Comment: A lot of things are disrupted now due to coronavirus. But no one should be "forced" to put their health and lives at risk for you.

Comment: Hi @Buffy , thanks very much for the response, I shall accept being homeless next month.

Comment: Have you actually graduated? If so, you should already be in possession of your degree certificate. If you have only passed the viva but not officially graduated, the academic records office at your university should be able to provide you with proof of the PhD. Can you be clearer on their reason for refusing? Have you explained to your supervisor, head of department, admin etc that you need the documentation for your future employer? What did they say?

Comment: I sincerely hope you find an alternative to that.

Comment: Hi @astronat , yes I have passed my viva and corrections but have not yet had a graduation ceremony, the records office (and other administration) are refusing to provide this and other documents due to "not having the required software remotely". My supervisor stopped working for my university before I finished my PhD. The head of my department has been attempting to escalate the issue with the university administration teams for the past month but there is no movement on this issue.

Comment: It’s probably legal, given these extraordinary times. If you were on good terms with your department, I’d talk to your adviser if they’re comfortable to contact, or have the department head contact, administration trying to explain to them why it’s urgent.